# Synchronize with Google+ Photos

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos, google-sync

Im trying to sync my photos on google plus using my iphone, because i had more free space on it.

How do it sync in timely manner  - auto sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the [Google+ app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google+/id447119634?mt=8) onto your phone.

According to [Google's directions](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en):

Open the  Google+ app > touch the Menu icon > Gear icon > Camera and Photos > Auto Backup > Toggle On or Off

Allow Google+ to access your photos: Phone settings > Privacy > Photos > Google+ > toggle the setting ON or OFF